# How to add 'LIMIT :' to String in Database.query?

Tags: apex, query, database

I have Database.query that sorts records by a few filters (or any filter). I want to set the limit for it. How should a write it?

```
return Database.query('SELECT Id, Name FROM Stereo_System__c' + 
                     (filters.isEmpty() ? '' : ' WHERE ' + String.join(filters,' AND ')));
```

Comment: `Query  = Query+' LIMIT 2000' `will work. Are you facing any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
return Database.query('SELECT Id, Name FROM Stereo_System__c' + 
                     (filters.isEmpty() ? '' : ' WHERE ' + String.join(filters,' AND ')) + ' LIMIT 50000');
```